# How do I install NTP from source on CentOS v7? (/bin/ld: cannot find -lcap)

Tags: centos, compiling, make, configure, ntp

I unpacked the .tar.gz file.  I installed the gcc compiler.  I ran the ./configure command with various flags and options.  I ran `make check` and found an error.  The exit status is 2.  Only 0 is without errors.  In the output I see this:

> /bin/ld: cannot find -lcap collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
>   make[6]: *** [test-crypto] Error 1

The ld utility is installed.  I don't know what "-lcap" is.  I found one website that seemed to have lcap packages.  But the links were broken for Centos version 7.  If you post a place where I can download lcap (which is not installed on my CentOS 7 server), please confirm the link isn't broken.

How do I fix this error so I can use the make install command to get NTP installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't know what "-lcap" is

The `-l` flag to the GCC C compiler tells it to link in a [library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library_(computing)), in this case called `cap`, which is an abbreviated version of the library name.

The full name is `libcap.so.2.22` on CentOS 7, with the alias `libcap.so.2`. Chasing such details down is not your problem; leave it to the linker.

What does matter here is that you're missing the development package, which installs `libcap.so`, without the version number, which is what GCC's linker is looking for. It also installs a bunch more files which may also be necessary. So:

```
$ sudo yum install libcap-devel
```

That is a common pattern: to build programs using `libfoo`, you typically need to install `libfoo-devel` first.